# Remove .php extension from nested URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following url, and I simply want to hide the .php extension.

current url :

```
 localhost/api.php/test/pickup/10000
```

new url

```
localhost/api/test/pickup/10000
```

I've been looking around for an answer, but all I can find is a way to remove the .php extension if the url ends with it.

So I wonder how do you remove the extension if the url is nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+api\.php([^\ \?]*)
RewriteRule ^ /api/%1 [L,R]
```

Assuming that when you go to `localhost/api/test/pickup/10000` it actually resolves to what you want. Otherwise, you can try turning on multiviews:

```
Options +Multiviews
```